# Passing DataContext to Get method to be able to update the returned object (VB.NET, LinqToSql)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

This is both a How Do I and a Should I question.

I have a method where I first want to check if an object exists in a database. If it does, then update that entry with Properties from the object. If not, then add that object to the database. This is for objects that are Models in MVC. So instead of writing out another Linq query, I'd like to simply call a Get() function and then update the returned object.

Example:

```
Class CustomerController

Function GetCust(cust As Customer) As Customer

    Dim db = New DataContext()

    'assume primary key is compared to it's not null default instead of Nothing'
    Return (From theCust In db.Customer
                 Where (cust.Property1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso theCust.Property1 = cust.Property1) _
                 AndAlso (cust.Property2 IsNot Nothing AndAlso theCust.Property2 = cust.Property2)
                 'etc
                 Select theCust).SingleOrDefault()

End Function

Function InsertOrUpdateCust(cust As Customer)

    Dim db = New DataContext()

    Dim retCust = GetCust(cust)

    If retCust IsNot Nothing Then
        retCust.Property1 = cust.Property1
        retCust.Property2 = cust.Property2
        'etc
    Else
        db.Customer.InsertOnSumbit(cust)
    End If

    db.SubmitChanges()

End Function

End Class
```

That InsertOrUpdateCust function is what I'd LIKE to do. So I don't have to have two instances of the query from GetCust. Since the Customer object that is returned by GetCust is taken from a different DataContext it isn't attached to the DataContext that's in the InsertOrUpdateCust function.

There is a lot I've found on .Attach() but both questions and answers seem confused on how/when to use it. Would that work here? If so, how? Or could I maybe pass the DataContext like so?

```
Function GetCust(cust As Customer, Optional dContext As DataContext = Nothing)
    Dim db = If(dContext Is Nothing, New DataContext(), dContext)
    Return thequery.SingleOrDefault()
End Function
```

Or should I stop trying and just copy the query?

This came up from an import from XLS task for which Insert/Update together is preferable, but maybe this kind of thing is useful more generally.

Thanks!